# Match Any Word Inside Cell With Any Word In Range of Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, udf

I have a list of phrases. I would like to check if any new terms match that list partially by word.

I'm looking for a code to implement fuzzy matching on the list to return the cell that has a close match.

**Example Data:**

[image]

```
Phrases,Terms
real term,new words
great work,new term
check phrase,more phrase
example here,great alpha
phrase random,beta new
```

**Desired Output:**

[image]

```
Phrases,Term,Match
real term,new words,No match
great work,new term,real term
check phrase,more phrase,check phrase/phrase random
example here,great alpha,great work
phrase random,beta new,No match
```

**What I've got:**

I tried using the following code to match the cell if it is found:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*" & B2 & "*",A:A, 0)), "No Match", VLOOKUP("*" & B2 & "*",A:A,1,FALSE))
```

However, the code only matches the entire cell. How can I make it match any word in the cell? This would create a fuzzy match. Any positive input is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any VBA code yet?

Comment: Hey @CallumDA33, not yet. I'm not very good with excel code. More versed in linux and bash. Would be happy to try/learn whatever you guys suggest :-) Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (rough and ready) VBA solution to your question. You will need to insert it into a code module in the VBA editor and then you can run the macro to get your desired output

```
Sub FindSimilar()
    Dim phrases As Range, phrase As Range
    Dim terms As Range, term As Range
    Dim matches As String
    Dim words() As String

    'ensure this has the correct sheet names for your workbook
    Set phrases = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A6")
    Set terms = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D6")

    For Each term In terms
        matches = vbNullString
        words() = Split(term.Value)

        For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
            For Each phrase In phrases
                If InStr(1, phrase.Value, words(i)) Then
                    matches = matches & phrase & "/"
                End If
            Next phrase
        Next i

        If matches <> vbNullString Then
            term.Offset(0, 5).Value = Left(matches, Len(matches) - 1)
        Else
            term.Offset(0, 5).Value = "No match"
        End If
    Next term
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @CallumDA33, this works great with my example. I'm just testing it out on some of our data. 2 questions. How can I reference a different sheet (Sheet2, same workbook) for phrases range? And, where to I change the column for the match output? I would effectively be have the terms in column D and matches in column I (capital i)

Comment: I've updated the code for the following things: 1. see the `set` commands for the phrases and terms references - make sure they are pointing to your data. I have now changed them as you requested. 2. At the bottom see the `term.Offset()` lines, they are offsetting column D (from definition of `terms`) by 5 columns - that is, column `I` as requested. Try to make sure you're understand what it's doing so that you can make small changes yourself if needed

Comment: Awesome! Trying it out now. And yes, I'm so new to it. I did try looking it up to understand the syntax a bit. Your direction is very helpful. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: My pleasure, more than happy to help

Comment: Hey @CallumDA33, I'm pretty sure I got my file names and cells right, however, I'm getting a "Run-time error '424': Object required". Does that mean I'm not calling the right cells?

Comment: if you press debug, which line has it thrown the error on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128399/discussion-between-callumda33-and-domainsfeatured).