# How To Blacklist Words In VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following script that [matches any word in a cell to any other word in a range of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661523/match-any-word-inside-cell-with-any-word-in-range-of-cells). However, I would like the code to omit certain common terms like "and, or, big, small".

I'm not very good with VBA, so I was hoping someone might be able to tell me where to add it into the code:

```
Sub FindSimilar()
Dim phrases As Range, phrase As Range
Dim terms As Range, term As Range
Dim matches As String
Dim words() As String

'ensure this has the correct sheet names for your workbook
Set phrases = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Export").Range("B2:B2000")
Set terms = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Topics").Range("D100:D3000")

For Each term In terms
    matches = ""
    words() = Split(term.Value)

    For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
        For Each phrase In phrases
            If InStr(1, phrase.Value, words(i)) Then
                matches = matches & phrase & "/"
            End If
        Next phrase
    Next i

    If matches <> vbNullString Then
        term.Offset(0, 6).Value = Left(matches, Len(matches) - 1)
    Else
        term.Offset(0, 6).Value = "No match"
    End If
Next term
End Sub
```

How can I blacklist terms in the code? Your positive input and support is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can place a `Select Case` statement inside the `For Each Loop`

```
For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
    Select Case words(i)
        Case = "and","or","big","small","whatever else you want to add"
        Case Else
            For Each phrase In phrases
                If InStr(1, phrase.Value, words(i)) Then
                    matches = matches & phrase & "/"
                End If
            Next phrase
    End Select
Next i
```

However, this will get unwieldy if there are a large amount of terms.

If there are a large amount of terms you can store the BlackListed Terms on a worksheet and then do something like this:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Topics").Range("BlackList").Find(words(i),lookat:=xlWhole) is Nothing Then 
            For Each phrase In phrases
                If InStr(1, phrase.Value, words(i)) Then
                    matches = matches & phrase & "/"
                End If
            Next phrase
    End If
Next i
```

*assumes BlackList is a namedrange. If not just replace with `A1:A100` or whatever the range is.*

Comment: Actually, I got the first term to work! The ones after the first comma don't work though.

Comment: Change `Case <> "and","or","big","small","whatever else you want to add"` to `Case "and", "or", "big", "small", "whatever else you want to add"` followed by `Case Else` (The current format is testing `(<> "and") OR (= "or") OR (= "big") etc`)

Comment: @YowE3K, that helped, but for some reason, certain terms like small are still being left in

Comment: @SMeaden `Case Is <> "and", "or", "big", "small", "whatever else you want to add"` is interpreted as `Case Is <> "and", Is = "or", Is = "big", Is = "small", Is = "whatever else you want to add"` and will evaluate to true as if the statement is `If testexpression <> "and" Or testexpression = "or" Or testexpression = "big" ....` - i.e. it inserts `Or` between each expression.

Comment: Okay, just to update, @SMeaden is correct. It autocorrects to `Case Is <> "and", "or", "big", "small", "whatever else you want to add"` However, that only works for the first term. The following terms are not blacklisted.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured - is it "small" that is being left in, or something like "Small" - it will be case-sensitive unless extra code is used.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, can you see why it would only work for the first term? Your code is nearly perfect.

Comment: @YowE3K, it's leaving "small", I made it's the same case

Comment: @DomainsFeatured - Ah, I remember running across this issue in the past with `<>` in `Case` statements. See my edit and try again.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured Not sure why "small" got past my suggestion, but not Scott's identical (apart from the leading [default] `=`) but as long as it works that's great.