# How To Set Case To Omit Any Words Less Than X Characters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with the following loop. I have a case that omits or [blacklists certain words in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271023/how-to-blacklist-words-in-vba-code). However, I would like to omit any words that are less than 3 characters.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
    Select Case words(i)
        Case = "and","or","big","small","whatever else you want to add"
        Case Else
            For Each phrase In phrases
                If InStr(1, phrase.Value, words(i)) Then
                    matches = matches & phrase & "/"
                End If
            Next phrase
    End Select
Next i
```

Anyone know how to do that? I'm thinking `Case => "[something for 3 characters]"` to be inserted along with the additional code. You positive input and support is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the length of the word:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
    If Len(words(i)) > 2 Then
        Select Case words(i)
            Case = "and", "big", "small", "whatever else you want to add"
            Case Else
                For Each phrase In phrases
                    If InStr(1, phrase.Value, words(i)) Then
                        matches = matches & phrase & "/"
                    End If
                Next phrase
        End Select
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: @DomainsFeatured - I'm not sure whether I deserved any reputation upvote for that answer - it was way too easy.

Comment: @DomainsFeatured P.S.  You might benefit from reading up on some of the VBA functions: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim forbiddenWordsArr As Variant
Dim forbiddenWords As String

forbiddenWordsArr= Array("and","or","big","small","whatever else you want to add")
forbiddenWords="|" & Join(forbiddenWordsArr,"|"), & "|"
For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
    Select Case True
        Case = Len(words(i))<3 or InStr(forbiddenWords, "|" & words(i) & "|") > 0

        Case Else

   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked back at the original link you posted leading in to this.

I think you would be better off removing all the unnecessary words (your blacklist and less than 3 characters) which this `Regexp` does, leaving the white-listed words in a 1D array for use with your phrases.

```
Dim StrIn As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim Words

StrIn = Join(Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Topics").Range("D1:D3000")), Chr(32))

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
  .Pattern = "\b([a-z]{1,2}|and|or|big|small)\b"
  .Global = True
  .ignorecase = True
StrIn = Application.Trim(.Replace(StrIn, vbNullString))
End With

Words = Split(StrIn, Chr(32))
```